# Distinguishing clipped values in `colorbar`

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a `pcolormesh` plot wherein the color map is clipped by setting `vmin` and and `vmax` to strictly within the range of the values plotted. Is there a way to have the associated `colorbar` detatch a chunk from the bottom and from the top to signify that the relevant colors are outside the range of the color map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `extend = both` keyword for the colorbar, and then set the over and under colors for the colormap of the pcolormesh object

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=np.random.rand(10,10)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

p=ax.pcolormesh(data,vmin=0.2,vmax=0.8,cmap='gray')

p.cmap.set_over('red')
p.cmap.set_under('blue')

fig.colorbar(p,extend='both')

plt.show()
```

[image]