# How can I add triangles to a ggplot2 colorbar in R to indicate out of bound values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit, colorbar

I'd like to make a plot using `ggplot2` where some of the fill values are clipped, i.e. values above or below the limits of the color scale are displayed as the minimum/maximum color. I can get this to work like this, using a combination of `limit` and `oob` (out of bounds):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot() + ... + scale_fill_viridis(na.value="white", limit=c(0, 10), oob=squish)
```

But there is no information in the colorbar that indicates there are values present outside of the limits.
How can I reproduce this matplotlib example in ggplot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32072348

Specifically, how to get the triangles at the end of the colorbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is not a package that implements triangle ends for colourbars in ggplot2 (but please let me know if there is!). However, we can implement our own. We'd need a constructor for our custom guide and a way to draw it. Most of the stuff is already implemented in `guide_colourbar()` and methods for their class, so what we need to do is just tag on our own class and expand the `guide_gengrob` method. The code below should work for vertically oriented colourbars. You'd need to know some stuff about the `grid` package and `gtable` package to follow along.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

my_triangle_colourbar <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colourbar(...)
  class(guide) <- c("my_triangle_colourbar", class(guide))
  guide
}

guide_gengrob.my_triangle_colourbar <- function(...) {
  # First draw normal colourbar
  guide <- NextMethod()
  # Extract bar / colours
  is_bar <- grep("^bar$", guide$layout$name)
  bar <- guide$grobs[[is_bar]]
  extremes <- c(bar$raster[1], bar$raster[length(bar$raster)])
  # Extract size
  width  <- guide$widths[guide$layout$l[is_bar]]
  height <- guide$heights[guide$layout$t[is_bar]]
  short  <- min(convertUnit(width, "cm",  valueOnly = TRUE),
                convertUnit(height, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE))
  # Make space for triangles
  guide <- gtable_add_rows(guide, unit(short, "cm"),
                           guide$layout$t[is_bar] - 1)
  guide <- gtable_add_rows(guide, unit(short, "cm"),
                           guide$layout$t[is_bar])
  
  # Draw triangles
  top <- polygonGrob(
    x = unit(c(0, 0.5, 1), "npc"),
    y = unit(c(0, 1, 0), "npc"),
    gp = gpar(fill = extremes[1], col = NA)
  )
  bottom <- polygonGrob(
    x = unit(c(0, 0.5, 1), "npc"),
    y = unit(c(1, 0, 1), "npc"),
    gp = gpar(fill = extremes[2], col = NA)
  )
  # Add triangles to guide
  guide <- gtable_add_grob(
    guide, top, 
    t = guide$layout$t[is_bar] - 1,
    l = guide$layout$l[is_bar]
  )
  guide <- gtable_add_grob(
    guide, bottom,
    t = guide$layout$t[is_bar] + 1,
    l = guide$layout$l[is_bar]
  )
  
  return(guide)
}
```

You can then use your custom guide as the `guide` argument in a scale.

```r
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = drat))

g + scale_colour_viridis_c(
    limits = c(3, 4), oob = scales::oob_squish,
    guide = my_triangle_colourbar()
  )
```

[image]

There isn't really a natural way to colour out-of-bounds values differently, but you can make very small slices near the extremes a different colour.

```r
g + scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", scales::viridis_pal()(255), "hotpink"),
    limits = c(3, 4), oob = scales::oob_squish,
    guide = my_triangle_colourbar()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is truly awesome! Have you considered asking for this function to be included in ggplot?

Comment: No, ggplot2 would typically defer this to an extension package, as the maintaining and improving the core of ggplot2 is already a lot of work. They [don't "officially" support guide extensions](https://ggplot2-book.org/extensions.html#new-guides), but there are signs that guides will become officially extendable in the future.

Comment: This is a very neat solution and works smoothly for continuous color scales, @teunbrand! Unfortunately, I failed to apply it for a discrete color scale (e.g. if drat in the example above was cut() with breaks defined as c(-Inf,seq(3,4,0.1),Inf)). Would it be possible to adapt your solution to print the triangles for the ending boxes of a discrete color scale? Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I've been working on a more generalised solution than this, but it requires a specific PR to be accepted by ggplot2, so I don't have any solution at the moment.

Comment: Thanks anyways for the immediate reply!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(gg.layers)
library(ggplot2)
library(rcolors)

brk <- c(-Inf, -1, 0, 1, 3, 6, 9, Inf)
nbrk <- length(brk) - 1
cols <- get_color(rcolors$amwg256, nbrk)

g <- make_colorbar(
  at = brk, col = cols, height = 1,
  tck = 0.4,
  space = "right",
  legend.text.location = c(0.3, 0.5),
  legend.text.just = c(0.5, 0.5),
  # legend.text = list(fontfamily = "Times", cex = 1.1),
  hjust = 0.05
)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p + g
```

https://github.com/rpkgs/gg.layers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Triangles? No idea. Colors? You can set a gradient with custom values where your normal range is manually defined and your extremes are something else.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# example taken from ?viridis::scale_colour_viridis, even if I don't use that function
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
d <- ggplot(dsub, aes(x, y, colour=diff)) + geom_point()
d +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colours=c("red", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "red"),
    values = c(0, 0.1-1e-9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9+1e-9, 1),
    breaks = c(-0.51, -.4, 0, .4, .62),
    label = function(z) replace(z, c(1, length(z)), c("Min", "Max"))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot2 with gradients and red ends]

I doubled `"red"` on each end so that there would be no gradient transition with the neighboring colors. You can choose a different color for one end (while in this case it's clear if it's extreme-high or extreme-low).

I chose to manually control `values=` and `labels=` to include arbitrary points and labels for the extremes. This can be improved based on your preferences.

The disadvantage to this is that you have to define the viridis colors manually; should not be too difficult. I've hastily approximated it here, I'm confident you can choose better colors for the internal gradient portion.