# how to use a triangular colorbar legend instead of rectangular one?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have continuous data and would like to have a colorbar legend whose size gradually increases with legend labels. How can I do that ideally with ggplot2 or any other package? Like a triangular colorbar rather than a rectangular one.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = length))+
theme_minimal()+
geom_point()+
[To DO ]
```

I googled the problem with no success!

Comment: Do you want to see a colorbar with triangle ends?

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440366/how-can-i-add-triangles-to-a-ggplot2-colorbar-in-r-to-indicate-out-of-bound-valu)

Comment: @Kat no, I want a triangular colorbar

Comment: @manro no, the entire colorbar should be triangle

Comment: Can you add an image or what you're looking for? (It can be hand drawn...) I'm having trouble imagining how it would look, yet still be meaningful.