# follow up on 'How can I add triangles to a ggplot2 colorbar in R to indicate out of bound values?'

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit, colorbar

In this question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440366/how-can-i-add-triangles-to-a-ggplot2-colorbar-in-r-to-indicate-out-of-bound-valu)) a solution was proposed for vertical color bar. I wonder if a more general solution, or a package, has been developed since then that can be applied also to horizontal color bars.

I tried to apply the proposed solution to a horizontal colorbar but it doesn't work. I also tried to manipulate the parameter but I don't really know how they work.

EDIT: I solved the problem following the solution suggested by [teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) in the before mentioned question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440366/how-can-i-add-triangles-to-a-ggplot2-colorbar-in-r-to-indicate-out-of-bound-valu)) and modifying the code as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

my_triangle_colourbar <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colourbar(...)
  class(guide) <- c("my_triangle_colourbar", class(guide))
  guide
}

guide_gengrob.my_triangle_colourbar <- function(...) {
  # First draw normal colourbar
  guide <- NextMethod()
  # Extract bar / colours
  is_bar <- grep("^bar$", guide$layout$name)
  bar <- guide$grobs[[is_bar]]
  extremes <- c(bar$raster[1], bar$raster[length(bar$raster)])
  # Extract size
  width  <- guide$widths[guide$layout$l[is_bar]]
  height <- guide$heights[guide$layout$t[is_bar]]
  short  <- min(convertUnit(width, "cm",  valueOnly = TRUE),
                convertUnit(height, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE))
  # Make space for triangles
  guide <- gtable_add_cols(guide, unit(short, "cm"),
                           guide$layout$l[is_bar] - 1)
  guide <- gtable_add_cols(guide, unit(short, "cm"),
                           guide$layout$l[is_bar])
  
  # Draw triangles
  left <- polygonGrob(
    x = unit(c(0, 1, 1), "npc"),
    y = unit(c(.5, 0, 1), "npc"),
    gp = gpar(fill = extremes[1], col = NA)
  )
  right <- polygonGrob(
    x = unit(c(0, 0, 1), "npc"),
    y = unit(c(0, 1, .5), "npc"),
    gp = gpar(fill = extremes[2], col = NA)
  )
  # Add triangles to guide
  guide <- gtable_add_grob(
    guide, left, 
    t = guide$layout$t[is_bar],
    l = guide$layout$l[is_bar] - 1
  )
  guide <- gtable_add_grob(
    guide, right,
    t = guide$layout$t[is_bar],
    l = guide$layout$l[is_bar] + 1
  )
  
  return(guide)
}
```

More precisely, I modified the 'make space for triangles' section adding cols before and after the bar and designing the polygonGrob as necessary. It seems to work but actually I do not really know what I have done and if there is another and more elegant way to do it. Here below a basic example:

```
df<-data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10), z = seq(1,20,2))


ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = z)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(limits = c(1,10), oob = scales::squish,
                        guide = my_triangle_colourbar()) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3BJl.png)

Comment: Hi Riccardo. If you have a specific example that you can show us with sample data and code, then describe your desired output in a bit more detail we could help you. As it stands, your question sounds like a request for package recommendations, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to make it on-topic, as I think it is an interesting and useful question.

Comment: I tried to update the question. Actually, it is more a review request since I am not used to work with grid and gtable packages