How can I add triangles to a ggplot2 colorbar in R to indicate out of bound values with ggproto?
This question was already posted and answered (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68442175/9827817). The code provided in the answer works perfectly. However, with the release of ggplot2 version 3.5.0, the NextMethod() function and subclassing ggplot2's guides with the S3 system have stopped working (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.5.0)).
Is it possible to get an updated version of the previous reply that is compatible with ggproto?
I do not know how to manage ggproto, so I am unsure how to modify the code myself.
